# Need to change date variable with drop down menu selection dynamically in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a php file (index.php) which has a titlebar, the titlebar holds date as (MM YYYY). The dates are pulled from another php file titled latest_update.php. The dates are listed in the latest_update file using the following syntax

```
$latest_run="April 2017";
$latest_run2="May 2017";
```

The $latest_run date is stripped from the file and passed to a variable using the following.

```
include_once "scripts/latest_update.php";
$mainTitle = "Content Title";
$secondaryTitle = $latest_run;
$thirdTitle = $latest_run2;
```

The title and date are held in a div using span

```
   <div class="titleBar">
   <span class="mainTitle"><?php echo $mainTitle ?></span></br>            
   <span Class="secondaryTitle"><?php echo $secondaryTitle ?></span>
   </div>
```

I have a selection menu and when I change the selection menu I want the option of the secondaryTitle to change. So if I select Run2 as the option I want the title to change to reflect May 2017 which corresponds to $thirdTitle. If I select Run1 I want it to change to the Secondarytitle referring to April 2017. The select menu is held within a form.

```
 <form id="myForm">
 <select style="visibility:visible;position:relative;left:0px;top:1px;font-size:12px" name="selmenu" id="selmenu">
 <option value="Run1">Run1</option>
 <option value="Run2">Run2</option>
 <option value="Run3">Run3</option>
 </select>
 </form>
```

I am new to php and have not been able to find a solution to complete this action. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: at first, have a look at arrays

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

Try something to this effect: (requires JQuery and Ajax)

```
JS -gets data from your form selection, sends it to your php file, then appends the response to the title 


    $(document).ready(function()
    var runChoice = $("#selectRun").val();
    $.ajax({
              url: 'latest_update.php',
              type: 'POST',
              data: {run:runChoice},
              success: function(response){
                  $(".secondaryTitle").append(response);
                }
    )};
)};
```

PHP Side - gets data from ajax

```
$choice = $_POST['runChoice'];
if($choice == "Run1"){
    echo $latest_run;
}else if($choice == "Run2"){
    echo $latest_run2;
}else{
    echo $latest_run3;
}
```

This could be completed entirely without a PHP file though if you don't need database related things, you could store the values for run dates into an array, then just change the title based on the selected option without using ajax and just using appends.

Comment: My index.php already has a lot of other content. I have jquery initiated in the head of my file, I believe ajax too. My question is where would I be placing this code? Wouldit need to be a separate file?

Comment: Well, the JS can go in a separate file and then you can script src it , or place it in <head></head> in the page of your HTML form.  The PHP would go in the page containing your dates, but make sure you're only echoing those because the code I gave you would return whatever is echoing . You could put an if(isset($_POST['runChoice']) { } around all that to prevent that though

Comment: So I found out that I can't use ajax, it is not an option for me. also the php file with the dates is not a page, it is a dynamically created file when processing is run. This essentially must all be done within the index.php page.

Comment: @J.R.W how about including all the files into index.php, creating `<input type = 'hidden' value=<?php echo run1; ?>' id='run1' />,  then using JavaScript/JQuery to grab those hidden values, then on change of your select, use that value and append/put it into the secondaryTitle span. WITHOUT AJAX, you cannot interact with PHP in any way, you need that interaction from front end - back end, without what I said (creating html fields on page load, php is done first always), you can't get those values any other way

Comment: Why is AJAX not an option? Is it for a project or? Because Ajax is included within JQuery

Comment: Ok I went back and spoke with the person, he wasn't clear in what he was saying. He was saying you don't declare agax separatley from jquery in head(which is basically what you just said). I was confused by that because I've seen ajax used before. I am basically making changes to a page that was already existing so that it can display more than one data type. When I put the document ready (function etc. into the head I placed it below the src tags. Something seems to be wrong with it though, it is just purple.Using your syntax from above.

Comment: I believe I had to do this within.  <script src="jquery(not exact)"></script>

Comment: No, Ajax is a method used within your JS file or <script tags> in $(document).ready(function() { }); code.

Comment: <span Class="secondaryTitle"><?php  $choice = $_POST['runChoice'];
                                        if($choice == "Run1"){
                                        echo $latest_run;
                                        }
                                        else if($choice == "Run2"){
                                        echo $latest_run2;} ?></span>

Comment: <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var runChoice = $("#selmenu").val();
    $.ajax({
              url: 'scrips/latest_update.php',
              type: 'POST',
              data: {run:runChoice},
              success: function(response){
                  $(".secondaryTitle").append(response);
                }
    )};
)};
</script><

Answer (score 0):

To change the content of the "secondaryTitle" you have to use javascript below:

```
function setTitle(select) {
        var value = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;

        if (value == "Run2") {
            var secondTitle = document.getElementsByClassName('secondaryTitle')[0].innerHTML;
            document.getElementsByClassName('mainTitle')[0].innerHTML = secondTitle;
        }
    }
```

and change the select tag to:

```
<select style="visibility:visible;position:relative;left:0px;top:1px;font-size:12px" name="selmenu" id="selmenu" onchange="setTitle(this);">
    <option value="Run1">Run1</option>
    <option value="Run2">Run2</option>
    <option value="Run3">Run3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I tried to make it simple by just javascript @J.R.W

Comment: This won't work because it isn't getting the data in the PHP file, where his dates are located

Comment: How does this pull in the dates though? I'm confused.

Comment: It pulls the content of your spans by this code:  document.getElementsByClassName('secondaryTitle')[0].innerHTML

Comment: You need to do some studies about javascript (JQuery is an advanced library for Javascript)